# C# How to attach additional information to every call in NetTcpBinding?

Tags: c#, wcf

How one can attach, for example, client version in every WCF call over net.tcp binding?

I tried to attach it like this:

```
        MessageHeader<string> header = new MessageHeader<string>(SerializeVersion());
        MessageHeader untypedHeader = header.GetUntypedHeader(VERSION_HEADER, Namespace);
        OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(untypedHeader);
```

But unfortunetly, OperationContext is not available during first call...

Answer (score 0):

If there is no OperationContext, then create your own:

```
void MyMethod()
{
  using (var proxy = new WcfProxy())
  {
    using (var scope = new OperationContextScope((IContextChannel)proxy))
    {
      MessageHeader header = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("VERSION_HEADER", "ns", SerializeVersion());
      OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(header); 

      proxy.ExecuteOperation() // Call you service
    }
  }
}
```